# Why is the set ${\{1\}}$ closed on $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $d(x,y) = |x−y|$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

On the real line $\mathbb{R}$, if one uses the usual metric $d(x,y) = |x−y|$, then the set ${\{1\}}$ is not open, however if instead one uses the discrete metric $d_{disc}$, then ${\{1\}}$ is now an open set.

I don't quite understand the reasoning behind the above statement. Also would it be closed on $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z}?$

I know that a space is defined as closed, if it contains its boundary, but for the set ${\{1\}}$ I am not sure which is the boundry?

Comment: The question in the title does not match the one in the body.

Comment: You have to apply the definition of "open".  Please show your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, a better (and equivalent) definition of closed is: $A$ is closed if and only if $\Bbb{R}\setminus A$ is open. So, in the usual topology, pick any real number $x$ not in the set $\{ 1 \}$. Clearly there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ does not include $1$. Thus the complement of $\{ 1 \}$ is open, so $\{ 1 \}$ is closed.

If you would rather use the "contains its boundary" definition, then consider this: $1$ is in the boundary with the usual metric because every open ball around $1$ will contain both the point $1$ and points not in $\{ 1 \}$. So, $1$ is in the boundary, and it is in the set, so the set contains its boundary.

In the discrete metric, $\{ 1 \}$ *is* the ball with radius $1/2$ centered at 1, so it contains an open ball around all of its points, and is thus open.

Answer (score 1):

The set {1} is closed if its complement is open. In this case the complement of {1} is $ ℝ\setminus${1}.

$$ ℝ\setminus{1} = \left]-\infty, 1\right[ \cup \left]1, +\infty\right[$$

Which is the union of two open sets, therefore is an open set.

If $ℝ\setminus${1} is open then {1} is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If a set $X$ is equipped with the discrete metric then all singletons are open because $\{p\} = \{x\in X : d(x,p) < 1\}$.

If we equip $\Bbb R$ with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, then $\{1\}$ is closed because its complement is open (any point in the complement is positive distance away from $1$). Also bear in mind that "open" is not the same as "not closed" because a set can be both open and closed.

Answer (score 0):

A set is closed iff its complement is open. Consider $S=\mathbb{R} - \{1\}$. Then if $x\in S$ it’s not hard to find a neighborhood contained in $S$ and containing $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is referred to as open if for any $x\in A$ we have an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\subset A$ either where $$B_\epsilon(x)=\{a:d(a,x)<\epsilon\}$$ By using discrete metric such thing happens for every $\epsilon<1$ because:$$B_\epsilon(x)=\{a:d(a,x)<\epsilon<1\}=\{a:d(a,x)=0\}=\{a\}\subset A$$which implies on openness. Also it is closed so a more likely phrase is "Clopen" which are both open and closed. Also since it is clopen in $\Bbb R$ so is in $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Z$ according to "Inheritance principle".